# White light reflections show up as ugly white patches

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, lighting, reflection

I have a nicely done texture of a costume. Notice the texture already has 3D effect and nice light reflections. But when I UV mapped it onto the model, they simply render as ugly white patches.   I tried playing around with glossy BSDF mixed with diffused BSDF shading, but they reflect light in wrong places.

[image: Image of texture vs render]

How do I improve on this such that the white light reflections render properly as actual light reflection instead of ugly white patches?

Your advice is greatly appreciated!